# What scripture descibes the story of Goddess Kalikrishna?

Tags: krishna, identification-request, kali

According to [this website](https://www.telegraphindia.com/1121114/jsp/calcutta/story_16192568.jsp), there is a place in Bengal where Goddess Kaali is worshiped as Lord Krishna and Her name is KaliKrishna. It says, once Radha was caught by Her husband when She was with Lord Krishna and to save Her, Krishna disguised Himself as Goddess Kaali.

> Kali is worshipped as Krishna in the house of the Banerjees of Sri Gopal Mallik Lane off College Square. Although the image is in keeping with the folk tale popular in Bengal of Krishna transforming himself into Kali when Radha’s husband, Ayan Ghosh, caught her red-handed with the blue god, it is rarely seen in Calcutta and much less worshipped here. Porcelain versions of this tale were available here in early 20th century but few of these have survived.

She is Goddess Kalikrishna,

[image]

What scripture mentions this story?

Comment: In places in the tantrik tradition, the Krishna avatar of Vishnu is often identified with Kali. May be this could be one of the reason why Goddess Kalikrishna.