# Goddess Kaali as Shri Krishna

Tags: krishna, avatars, kali

It is widely known that Lord Sri Krishna is the incarnation of Lord Vishnu. Yet recently I came across a story where it is said that Goddess Kaali incarnated as Lord Sri Krishna. Is this mentioned in any of the Puranas?

Comment: Not all accept Krishna is incarnation of Vishnu. Krishna is considered svayam bhagavan, source of all avatars. Check my answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30209/on-what-basis-is-krishna-claimed-to-be-source-of-vishnu

Comment: its found in the Todola-Tantra

Comment: its mentioned in devi-bhagavatam as well : https://www.boloji.com/articles/1362/how-devi-kali-became-krishna

Comment: [What scriptures describes the story of kalikrishna](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27848/6981) I asked similar question.

Comment: @KrishnaShweta Kali becoming Krishna and Krishna becoming Kali are two separate topics.

Comment: "Not all accept Krishna is incarnation of Vishnu" but they should. It is the only reasonable answer.

Comment: they need not. both sides are reasonable, infact Krishna being source of all is more reasonable according to me. For you it may be other way round.